# Are there any spiders in The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-hobbit, an-unexpected-journey

I suffer from a severe level of arachnophobia. in the description of the movie it says:

> Their journey will take them into the Wild; through treacherous lands
>   swarming with Goblins and Orcs, deadly Wargs and **Giant Spiders**,
>   Shapeshifters and Sorcerers.

I asked a friend of mine who watched the movie and he couldn't remember seeing any spider. so I wonder if anyone can confirm or deny that there are no visible spiders in this movie.

Comment: See also [Do the spiders return in The Hobbit - Battle of the Five Armies?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/28716/7454) and [Does “The Hobbit: The Desolation of Smaug” have spiders in it?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/15842/7454)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From inside Radagast's house you see shadows of spider attack, you see the legs of a spider break into the house before Radagast's magic seems to scare them off.

He emerges from the house and you clearly see giant spiders running away from the house.

So, contrary to the previous answers, I would say "yes" but it is brief and you don't see them fully.

Comment: Ah! Good point and well remembered.

Comment: Just watched it now, everything ian described is accurate.
for me, the entire scene was tolerable and didn't last more than a minuet or two. 

The giant spider you see at the very last 2-3 seconds of the sceen, is very far away that and you can barely see it.

Comment: @Esh - wow, that was a long time between asking the question and watching the movie. I'm glad you got to enjoy it.  Unfortunately the 'desolation of smaug' has much more significant scenes with spiders.

Answer (score 6):

The first part of *The Hobbit* trilogy, *An Unexpected Journey*, does not involve the [Giant Spiders](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Giant_Spiders). Going by [the book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hobbit), the second part, *The Desolation of Smaug*, very likely will.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I remember, no you don't actually see the spiders, they're just alluded to via shadows and such.